# pandas.read_parquet incorrectly interprets the date field

Tags: python, pandas, date, parquet

I have a parquet file with a date field in it called `'BusinessDate'`. When I import it to a dataframe, it automatically determines the field BusinessDate being a date (`datetime64[ns, UTC]`).

However, since the format of this `'BusinessDate'` field is `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, some of these dates were incorrectly imported. E.g. 2013-02-01 should be the first of February 2013 while it actually was interpreted as the second of January 2013.

Is it possible to set the correct format of the `'BusinessDate'` field when importing the parquet file?

Initially I used:

```
df.read_parquet('data.parquet')
```

If I had a csv file my solution would be:

```
custom_date_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
df.read_csv('data.csv',parse_dates=['BusinessDate'], date_parser=custom_date_parser)
```

However, when I try a comparable code to try to fix the date issue, it gives an error:

```
custom_date_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
df.read_parquet('data.parquet',parse_dates=['BusinessDate'], date_parser=custom_date_parser)
```

The error is caused due to the fact that the `read_parquet` function doesn't have a `parse_dates` or `date_parser` attribute, `read_csv` function does have.

So my question is: How do I import a parquet file in pandas so that the `'BusinessDate'` field is imported correctly as a date in the correct format which is `'YYYY-MM-DD'` in my case. Or in case this not possible with pandas `read_parquet` function, is it possible to import the `'BusinessDate'` field as a string field in a `pandas.DataFrame` so that I can change it afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

Great question.
Pandas doesn't have a feature for this yet.

Once you read the parquet, I recommend using your lambda function like so:

```
df['new_col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.0`**
- Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), and set the `format` parameter, which is the existing format, not the desired format.

  - Convert: `'%Y-%d-%m'` → `'%Y-%m-%d'`
  - `format` codes can be found at [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```py
df['BusinessDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BusinessDate'].astype(str), format='%Y-%d-%m').dt.date
```

- If [`.read_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) interprets a parquet `date` filed as a `datetime` (and adds a time component), use the [`.dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) to extract only the `date` component, and assign it back to the column.

```py
df['BusinessDate'] = ['BusinessDate'].dt.date
```

---

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
data = pd.date_range('2023-04-01', freq='20s', periods=50000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': data})

# display(df.head())
                 test
0 2023-04-01 00:00:00
1 2023-04-01 00:00:20
2 2023-04-01 00:00:40
3 2023-04-01 00:01:00
4 2023-04-01 00:01:20

# display(df.tail())
                     test
49995 2023-04-12 13:45:00
49996 2023-04-12 13:45:20
49997 2023-04-12 13:45:40
49998 2023-04-12 13:46:00
49999 2023-04-12 13:46:20

# convert to string and set the current format
df['test'] = pd.to_datetime(df['test'].astype(str), format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S').dt.date

# display(df.head())
         test
0  2023-01-04
1  2023-01-04
2  2023-01-04
3  2023-01-04
4  2023-01-04

# display(df.tail())
             test
49995  2023-12-04
49996  2023-12-04
49997  2023-12-04
49998  2023-12-04
49999  2023-12-04
```

---

#### `%timeit` comparison

```py
data = pd.date_range('2023-04-01', freq='20s', periods=50000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': data})

# comparison
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['test'].astype(str), format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S').dt.date  # result is a datetime.date Dtype
%timeit df['test'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%d-%m'))  # result is a str
%timeit df['test'].dt.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')  # result is a str
```

#### output

```
162 ms ± 1.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
175 ms ± 1.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
185 ms ± 1.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```